# How to use Malayalam dictionary on kindle

Tags: kindle, epub, kindle-paperwhite, download, dictionaries

I would like to use Malayalam dictionary on my kindle pw. I downloaded a Malayalam dictionary named "English-Malayalam dictionary by Gijo Varkey". I tried all formats of the dictionary viz azw3, epub and mobi. Still my kindle is not recognizing the file as a dictionary. I can read it as a book, but I want to use it as a dictionary. So, if anybody tried/knows and succeeded please do respond.